# How to associate and infer property types in typescript from given value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following example code that resembles the actual classes (I do not put the full class because is quite big.

```
type accepted = 'a' | 'b';

type objects = A | B;

class A {
    aprop: string[] = [];
    add(): void {}
}

class B {
    myprop: string = '';
    anotherprop: number = 1;
    add(): void {}
}

class C<T extends objects> {
    prop1: accepted;
    prop2: T;
    constructor (prop1: accepted, prop2: T) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}

const right1 = new C('a', new A());
const right2 = new C('b', new B());
const wrong1 = new C('a', new B()); //should not be possible
```

What I want is to make sure that whenever I instantiate a class C with certain value of `prop1` (a set of possible strings) the `prop2` shall be its correspondent class.

In other words, I want to infer that `prop2` is class A or B when the value of `prop1` is `'a'` or `'b'`.

In addition, a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgxnCZgQCZQLxQOQ21AHxwCNsBuAKAtEigHtiArCOYAZ0ygEFCoAhShTgAbGGw48A3hSizYYAE50wALihtgCgJYA7AOYBtALqdjlObFSoAFAEo1ANzpb0kgL4UPQ0eP5RpFgC24Eqq6pq6epzY5DJyMDp0wAAWEAqKymo6AK6BxGmcAIzm8VZ2js6uHl4iYhwAwgA8ACpQEAAeKDqoHAzMrGwAfP5xshlghWrwiMhoJWOhAExqzfNQcHQ6GgrZrHQKUNbjk7AISCioADRQ48tQzbYjFhYpWmwAdMecx2svyW+fJbfJZrapUDZbYBQbR6ZLAQqcHQQADuUHq1lw2GuSNRXDstkoEI00K0sOAi0RKLRGNI2KpfHxhM2xORSn0CKwOOpmLpqIZtgJUAA9EK2Mk6NlhOhElD8jc6OItMRhBAgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have two classes in this example, I think you should use the  [overloads example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#constructors).

```
class C<T extends objects> {
    prop1: accepted;
    prop2: T;
    constructor(prop1: 'a', prop2: A);
    constructor(prop1: 'b', prop2: B);
    constructor (prop1: accepted, prop2: T) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYZ9xw)

---

If you have more classes, you can use a map like this:

```
type ClassMap = {
    a: A;
    b: B;
}

class C<T extends accepted> {
    prop1: T;
    prop2: ClassMap[T];
    constructor (prop1: T, prop2: ClassMap[T]) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgxnCZgQCZQLxQOQ21AHxwCNsBuAKAtEigHtiArCOYAZ0ygEFCoAhShTgAbGGw48A3hSizYYAE50wALihtgCgJYA7AOYBtALqdjlObFSoAFAEo1ANzpb0kgL4UPQ0eP5RpFgC24Eqq6pq6epzY5DJyMDp0wAAWEAqKymo6AK6BxGmcAIzm8VZ2js6uHl400ADCPmwAsjBgnAHxalwlssRqAp5UImIcdQA8ACpQEAAeKDqoHPCIyGgAfP5xshlghWoTPVA7AExqDSMtYAYTRodwdDoaCtmsdApQ1jt7UBMANEehU5Qc7iS7XIy2TYWCwpLRsAB0X04X0OMOScMRgORgMO1SGDw0UG0emSwEKnB0EAA7sDrLhsP9KTSuHZbJR7o9gEStCTgMcKdTadhSIzBXxWeyCVyqUp9OSsEyhXhRTTxbY2VAAPSatjJOjZYToRJc-JHOjiLTEYQQIA)

Comment: do you know any alternative in case I want to add more classes?

Comment: I just added another possible solution which is better if you have more classes.